# Silverlight - Context Menu multiple items selected

Tags: silverlight

Using SL5 and the Silverlight Toolkit

Am using a right click on a ListBox, which works fine:

```
private void Person_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Account account = ((MenuItem)sender).DataContext as Account;
            UpdateText.Text = string.Format("Person selected on account: <{0}>", account.Username);
        }
```

If I have multiple ListBox items selected (SelectionMode="Extended"), I can only reference the 1 item in Person_Click

Question:  How to reference multiple items from a context menu?

Answer (for future people!)

```
 private void Person_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Account account = ((MenuItem)sender).DataContext as Account;
            UpdateText.Text = string.Format("Person selected on account: <{0}>", account.Username);

            //if multiple items are selected on right click this is how to reference them
            List<int> selectedItemIndexes = new List<int>();
            foreach (object o in AccountItemsT32.SelectedItems)
            {
                //selectedItemIndexes.Add(listBox.Items.IndexOf(o));
                var x = o;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Person_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Account account = ((MenuItem)sender).DataContext as Account;
            UpdateText.Text = string.Format("Person selected on account: <{0}>", account.Username);

            //if multiple items are selected on right click this is how to reference them
            List<int> selectedItemIndexes = new List<int>();
            foreach (object o in AccountItemsT32.SelectedItems)
            {
                //selectedItemIndexes.Add(listBox.Items.IndexOf(o));
                var x = o;
            }
        }
```